# How to stop an Upstart Job(Service)

Tags: 12.04, upstart, nginx

I thought this was easy but it does not seem to.

Here is my system info:

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0

# uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-0-247 3.2.0-69-virtual #103-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 2 05:21:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

And here are my various attempts at stopping NginX:

```
# netstat -punta | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1743/nginx -g daemo

# service nginx stop
nginx start/running, process 1775
# netstat -punta | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1775/nginx -g daemo

# nginx -s stop
# netstat -punta | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1783/nginx -g daemo

# nginx -s quit
# netstat -punta | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1791/nginx -g daemo

# initctl stop nginx
nginx start/running, process 1830
# netstat -punta | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1830/nginx -g daemo
```

As seen above, Every time I try to stop the NginX service, it comes alive with a new PID. Seeking help to stop NginX service gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo kill $(pgrep nginx)
```

**if not work try**

```
sudo pkill nginx
```

**if not work try** search for PID of the service:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

Then kill by PID:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Comment: I want to stay away from `kill`ing. There has to be an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619624/4026906) there's an incongruity between the nginx.conf file, and the init script that controls all of the 'service' actions.

The line `pid /tmp/nginx.pid;` should appear in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. This line should be copied into all of the actions within the script at `/etc/init.d/nginx` wherever there's a reference to pid. Then the top/reload/restart actions should all work.

Comment: This could be scripted so that the init script gets the pid file path from the nginx.conf file, so that the init script doesn't have to be updated if nginx.conf is updated.